SoundCloud widget api dispose / unload sound
Is there a method to dispose current playing sound?  I want to stop / upload sound (not just pause), then later load new sound again.
I dont see any info about disposing sound here:  https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#methods
Of course I could null the widget, then create again, but I want to avoid that.

"Unload" as in, wipe downloaded audio data from the browser cache? Or just current page memory? Either way, I doubt any such widget would have such fine-grained control over browser behavior. And it is probably not that much of a typical use case, that widget developers would put much time and effort into it, even if it was somehow possible.

Just like youtube has unload method, I guess it cleares video src on their side.

Sorry stopVideo for youtube
